# gmail api error in apps scripting + Insufficient permissions error code 403 domain global

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I have the Gmail API enabled and looked up all questions on stackoverflow to make sure I am not missing anything. Even after conforming all the options for the gmail API, I am getting the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

I am out of options and would like to understand where I am going wrong.

```
    var body = "<html><body>"
      + "<p>" + "Hi Team," + "<br/><br/>"
      + "<p>" + "Can you please review the bid for the following opportunity:" + "<br/>" 
      + "<p>" + "<u><b>Opportunity Details: </b></u>"+ "<br/>"  
      + "</body></html>";

      Logger.log(body);  
      var con = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Australia')); 
      var toList = [];
      for (var i in con) {
        toList[i] = "<" + con[i].getPrimaryEmail() + ">";  
      }  
      toList = toList.join(',');

      var msg = {
        to: toList,
        from: {
          name: ContactsApp.getContact(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()).getFullName(),
          email: Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),
          signature: Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs[0].signature
        },
        body: body,
        subject: sub
      };

      //  var htmlBody = '<p>Hello, I am an HTML message</p><br/>' + '<a href="---------------">Click here</a>';
      //  var signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs[0].signature    ;    //sendAs.filter(function(account){if(account.isDefault){return true}})[0].signature;

      var raw = 'From: <' + msg.from.email + '>\r\n' +
        'To: ' + msg.to + '\r\n' +
          'Subject:' + msg.subject + '\r\n' +
            'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n' + 
              '\r\n' + msg.body + msg.from.signature;

      var draftBody = Utilities.base64Encode(raw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8).replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-');

      var params = {
        method      : "post",
        contentType : "application/json",
        headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
        devMode     : true,
        muteHttpExceptions:true,
        payload:JSON.stringify({
          "message": {
            "raw": draftBody
          }
        })
      };

      var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts", params);
      Logger.log(resp);
      Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate `ScriptApp`? I would suspect you only ask for the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels`, and you need at least `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send` to send a message.

Comment: How do I add additional scopes in apps scripting? I activated Gmail API in advanced google services and also enabled gmail api for the project

Comment: I'm sorry, it should probably be automatic after configuration, my bad. Have you stumbled upon [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620359/insufficient-permissions-error-with-google-appscripts#answer-33660755)?

Comment: not yet. I am blown. Have tried diabling and enabling again but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by manually modifying the manifest file in the Google Scripts interface.

If you look under **File > Project Properties > Scopes**, you will find there are certain scopes for which the app is already requesting an authorization. You can manually add to these scopes by changing the json manifest file, under **View > Show manifest file** to add the ones in your Project Properties + the one you need for Gmail API, in my case, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose".

Hope it helps.

Comment: "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Gmail",
      "serviceId": "gmail",
      "version": "v1"
    }, {
      "userSymbol": "Slides",
      "serviceId": "slides",
      "version": "v1"
    }, {
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v2"
    }, {
      "userSymbol": "Plus",
      "serviceId": "plus",
      "version": "v1"
    }, {
      "userSymbol": "Sheets",
      "serviceId": "sheets",
      "version": "v4"
    }],

Comment: This is what I see in the manifest file...where in the manifest file do I add this scope?